# How Redirect Route Group Prefix To Other Page

Tags: php, laravel

I have this:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'manager', 'middleware' => ['auth' , 'CheckAdmin']  ] , function(){

route::get('/' , function(){
        return redirect()->back();
});

route::get('/dashboard' , 'ManagerController@index');
route::post('/sendpharmacy' , 'ManagerController@sendph');

});
```

My `checkadmin` middleware looks like:

```
if(auth()->check()) {
    if(auth()->user()->isAdmin())
            return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/pharmacist/dashboard');
}
```

I want Redirect /manager To other page but this Return 404 error. 
Please help me.

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: you have prefix as manager. so that group's all calls start after manager. for example www.yourappname/manager/dashboard, www.yourappname/manager/sendpharmacy.

Comment: @AshishPatel in out Of This Group I write route::get('manager' , function(){ return redirect()->back()); but stiil This retun error 404 in /manager

Comment: @madalinivascu i just want line 4 of My code , work :(

Comment: Try: `route::get('manager/dashboard' , function(){ return redirect()->back() });`

Comment: @HirenGohel dont want  redirect /manager/dashboard redirect , i just want /manager redirect To /manager/dashboard

Comment: Try to remove middleware groups and then try! I think issue is there.

Comment: @DeviCe show me the url after returning back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this
just change place Line Of redirect :)

```
route::get('/manager' , function(){
        return redirect()->back();
});

Route::group(['prefix'=>'manager', 'middleware' => ['auth' , 'CheckAdmin']  ] , function(){
route::get('/dashboard' , 'ManagerController@index');
route::post('/sendpharmacy' , 'ManagerController@sendph');

});
```

thank you All For helpinG :D

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'manager', 'middleware' => ['auth' , 'CheckAdmin']  ] , function() {

    Route::get('/' , function(){
        return redirect()->action('ManagerController@index');
    });

    Route::get('/dashboard' , 'ManagerController@index');
    Route::post('/sendpharmacy' , 'ManagerController@sendph');

});
```

Or you can skip redirect

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'manager', 'middleware' => ['auth' , 'CheckAdmin'] ] , function() {
    Route::get('/' ,              'ManagerController@index');
    Route::get('/dashboard' ,     'ManagerController@index');
    Route::post('/sendpharmacy' , 'ManagerController@sendph');
});
```

If you are getting 404, you need to check `CheckAdmin` middleware.

Comment: Your first code snippet answers better than the second one.

Comment: @VishalSharma while first snippet answers the question better (how to redirect), I'm just giving him another option

Comment: @DeviCe, can you add `CheckAdmin` middleware code to the question?

Comment: Try this answer with removing middleware groups! Issue is there. If you remove it, it should work.

Comment: @DeviCe does `/pharmacist/dashboard` path exist in your routes?

Comment: @VishalSharma yes

Comment: @ljubadr added  this to My question

Comment: @DeviCe, when do you get 404 error? when you visit **/manager**, or does it redirect you to **pharmacist/dashboard** and you get 404 on that page?

Comment: try `php artisan route:list --path=manager`, do you see 3 routes that were added? They should have URI `manager`, `manager/dashboard` and `manager/sendpharmacy`

Comment: @ljubadr yes added

Comment: @DeviCe In `Route::group(['prefix'=>'manager', 'middleware' => ['auth' , 'CheckAdmin']  ]...`, can you remove **CheckAdmin** and check if it works?

Comment: @ljubadr im Check It but 404 Error :(

Answer (score 0):

If you just want `/manager` to be redirected to `/manager/dashboard` (looking at your comments) then you can just do:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'manager' ] , function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return redirect('manager/dashboard');
    });

    Route::get('/dashboard', 'ManagerController@index');
    ...
});
```

Documentation often answers most of these questions.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redirects